# Promise IF condition always false JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, promise, httpresponse

I am using fetch to make an API call.  After successfully making the API call I get a good status code, but when trying to evaluate the status code my "if" statement always goes to "else" even though my status code is "200".  Please see the below snippet:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var accessToken = "Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>";
var url = '<URL>';
var headers3 = {
    'Authorization': accessToken
};

const delAPI = async url => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {method: "DELETE", headers: headers3});
        const res = await response.status;
        console.log(response.status);
        return res.status;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

delAPI(url).then(
    status => {
        const res = status;
        if (res === 200) {
            console.log("Integration has been deleted");
        } else {
            console.log("Integration is either disabled or not installed");
        }
    });
```

I think the issue is within the condition "(res === 200)" and it may not be evaluating "res" as my actual response.status from the async function delAPI?  I have tried numerous iterations to get around this and have had no luck thus far.  Any assistance is appreciated to get me going in the correct direction....

Comment: What does `console.log(res)` show?

Comment: Shouldn't you just return `res` as opposed to `response.status`, in `delAPI` definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        const res = await response.status;
    console.log(response.status);
    return res.status;
```

Your issue here is that the variable res already has the response.status http code in there, but you are returning res.status again, which should be undefined.

You just want to return either res, or response.status. Btw, I don't think you need to wait for the response.status. It's not a promise.

On a side note, we can do some slight refactoring here:

```
status => {
        if (status === 200) {
            console.log("Integration has been deleted");
        } else {
            console.log("Integration is either disabled or not installed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: yep....I declaring "const res = status;" was what caused the issues.  Thanks....still new to all of this and am learning :)